# TypeScript: Custom Request Types on Custom Express Router (TS2769)

Tags: typescript, express

I'm having difficulty getting custom Request types to play nicely with TypeScript.

In my app there are public and private routes.

The public routes use the `Request` type from Express. The private routes use a custom `PrivateRequest` type which extends the `Request` type from Express; which looks like this:

```js
import type { Request } from "express";
import type * as Cookies from "cookies";

export type PrivateRequest = Request & {
  user: User;
  cookies: Cookies;
}
```

Routing for the public and private routes looks like this:

```js
const publicRouter = express.Router();
const privateRouter = express.Router();

privateRouter.use([userSession]);

publicRouter.post("/login", login);
privateRouter.get("/api/user", user);
```

Here's an example of a private route, which makes use of the `PrivateRequest` type and there are no problems with TypeScript here.

```js
export default async function user(req: PrivateRequest, res: Response) {
  try {
    res.json({ test: true });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ errors: { server: "Server error" } });
  }
}
```

The issue is with the private routes, e.g.:

```js
privateRouter.get("/api/user", user);
```

The specific error I get back from TypeScript for the privately defined routes is this:

> TS2769: No overload matches this call

How can I fix this? Everything I try doesn't work, and I'm not entirely sure why.

I can fix this error if I make `user` nullable on the `PrivateRequest` but this is technically incorrect, since all of the private routes are guaranteed as user on the `req` object since the `userSession` middleware either responds with a 401 or adds the user to the `req` object for subsequent private routes. Here's an exmaple of whay my `userSession` middleware looks like:

```js
export default async function userSession(
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  try {
    req.cookies = new Cookies(req, res);

    // [...] authentication and user entity fetching (throws if either one fails)

    if (user === null) {
      res.status(401).json({ errors: { server: "Unauthorised" } });
    } else {
      // @ts-ignore
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  } catch {
    res.status(401).json({ errors: { server: "Unauthorised" } });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Express's `get` is defined to accept handlers accepting `Request`, not `PrivateRequest`, you'll have to reassure TypeScript that this is okay, that you know that `user` and `cookies` will be added to the request object. The way `get` is defined, TypeScript has to assume that your handler will just get a `Request`, not a `PrivateRequest`.

Here are two approaches for you:

1. Use a type assertion, probably in your own `get`-like utility function you'd use only for private routes:

   ```typescript
   const addPrivateGet = (path: string, handler: (req: PrivateRequest, res: Response)) => {
       privateRouter.get(path, handler as unknown as (req: Request, res: Response) => void);
   };
   // ...
   addPrivateGet("/api/user", user);
   ```
2. Alternatively, use an [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) in your private route handlers. Here's the assertion function:

   ```typescript
   function assertIsPrivateRequest(req: Request): asserts req is PrivateRequest {
       if (!("user" in req)) {
           throw new AssertionError(`Invalid request object, missing 'user'`);
       }
       if (!("cookies" in req)) {
           throw new AssertionError(`Invalid request object, missing 'cookies'`);
       }
   }
   ```

   Here's an example using it in a private route:

   ```typescript
   export default async function user(req: Request, res: Response) {
   // Note −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
     try {
       assertIsPrivateRequest(req); // <===== Narrows `req` to `PrivateRequest`
       // Now you can use `req.user` and `req.cookies` here
       res.json({ test: true });
     } catch (err) {
       console.error(err);
       res.status(500).json({ errors: { server: "Server error" } });
     }
   }
   ```

   The assertion function both narrows `req` to `PrivateRequest` and also provides a handy runtime check so you get a proactive error if you use it in a public route by mistake (or there's some problem with the middleware and your additional properties aren't added). (If you don't like the overhead of the `in` operations, you could do them only in development and staging but not production.)

---

It doesn't apply to your case where you want `Request` itself to be unchanged (for public routes) and to have a separate extended `PrivateRequest` type (for private routes), but for others who may find this answer: **If** you wanted to directly augment `Request` so the augmentations applied everywhere in your code, you could do that with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#handbook-content). To do that, have a file in your project that augments the interface, like this:

```typescript
// The types for Express use `e` as their namespace
declare module e {
    interface Request {
        someNewProperty: string;
    }
}
```

I *think* traditionally you'd name that file with a `.d.ts` extension (for instance, `express.augments.d.ts`), but you don't have to (and I could be mistaken).

That code adds `someNewProperty` directly to `Request`, globally, so this works:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.someNewProperty);
    // ...
});
```

This augmentation just does the type part of it, of course; it's up to your code to use middleware or similar to add the property so the type is accurate.

Comment: Is there really no better solution yet?

Comment: In the context of cleaner code. Having to create a separate function to assert the updated type is just a bit unclean in my eyes. Is there no way to perhaps simply extend the Request body type directly? I am not saying that this is necessarily bad but was simply wondering if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan - That's just one of the two solutions above. Personally, I prefer the other one: a simple function call in the private route that both handles the type issue and provides a proactive error if you accidentally use it on a public route (or there's some middleware issue). *"Is there no way to perhaps simply extend the Request body type directly?"* Yes, you can, but the OP needs this only on *some* routes, so they're using a different type. If you want to augment `Request` itself so the augmentation applies globally, you can do that...

Comment: ...with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#handbook-content). I'll add a bit to the answer showing doing that, since you may not be the only one wondering.

Comment: Ahh my bad, I somehow either missed that part of your answer when reading it Yesterday, or I did not understand it well. Apologies for the unnecessary ping.

Comment: That would be helpful.

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan - No worries, I think the answer was unclear about there being two alternatives. Thanks for flagging that up! I've updated the answer, clarifying the original and adding the example of declaration merging. Happy coding!